# Laravel input validation, alphanumeric but don't allow spaces

Tags: laravel

I have a field in a form which accepts a username. I need to use Laravels validation to validate the username but I'm struggling to come up with a solution which allows both alpha and numeric characters, but does not allow spaces in the username.

My Current validator looks like this;

```
$validatorFields = [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:150|regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9\-\s]+$/'
        ];
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this please?

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in `alpha_num` rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [alpha_num](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-alpha-num) The field under validation must be entirely alpha-numeric characters. Does not allow spaces as well.
Example:

```
$validatorFields = [
  'name' => 'required|string|max:150|alpha_num'
];
```